# for loop won’t stop looping and causes web page to crash

Tags: javascript, html

My code is looping through the coordinates in a feature collection in order to convert the feature collection to a polyline. However, the loop continues on and on, eventually causing my page to crash. I am a newbie and trying my best! Here’s the code:

```
var path [];
var networkLines;
for ( var I = 0; i < lines[‘features’][‘0’][‘geometry’][‘coordinates’][‘0’].length; i ++) {
     networkLines = lines[‘features’][‘0’][‘geometry’][‘coordinates’][‘0’][i];
     path.push({lat: parseFloat(networkLines[‘1’], lng:parseFloat(networkLines[‘0’])});
}
```

Comment: My code was a lot neater before I pressed submit!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: You declare a variable with a capital i, then use a lower case i in the conditional part of the `for` loop. You likely have errors in your console, as there are several other syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Get rid of the curly quotes around the strings. JavaScript only uses straight quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't post a comment yet...
I did notice that the is a missing closing parenthesis on the lat value
parseFloat(networkLines[‘1’]), and var i was declared in caps by mistake.
so the code becomes

```
var path [];
var networkLines;
for ( var i = 0; i < lines[‘features’][‘0’][‘geometry’][‘coordinates’][‘0’].length; i ++) {
    networkLines = lines[‘features’][‘0’][‘geometry’][‘coordinates’][‘0’][i];
    path.push({lat: parseFloat(networkLines[‘1’]), lng:parseFloat(networkLines[‘0’])});
}
```

This could cause weird errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = [];
var lines = [1, 2, 3];
lines.forEach(function (networkLines){
  path.push({ lat: networkLines });
})
```

you can do a forEach on an array

```
lines['features']['0']['geometry']['coordinates']['0'].forEach in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

`I` and `i` in JavaScript are different variables. So just change `I` to small `i`, because `i` is NaN, NaN++ === NaN